# Replace all occurrences in a string and avoid RegExp escaping

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Is that possible, without a loss of performance, to replace all occurrences of a substring with another string, and completely avoid using RegExp along the way? I.e. remove RegExp out of equation, just to make sure there is no RegExp magic happening when you forget to properly escape something like `+`.

```
'1+1 2+2'.replace('+', '-') -> only first "+" is replaced
'1+1 2+2'.replace(/\+/g, '-') -> undesired regexp complexities
```

UPDATE 1

This does not solve the escape problem:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll= function(search, replace) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(search, "g"), replace);
}
```

UPDATE 2

Doing programmatic unescape is a performance hit:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71788/discussion-on-question-by-exebook-replace-all-occurrences-in-a-string-and-avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceAll(str, search, replace) {
    while (str.indexOf(search) > -1) {
        str = str.replace(search, replace);
    }
    return str;
}
```

This works. However, is it more performant that using a regex? Let's try it.

Here is the regex function I benchmarked against:

```
function replaceAllRegex(str, search, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(search.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&"), 'g'), replace);
}
```

According to [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/replaceall-regex-or-not/6), the non-regex versions does ~8k ops/sec, while the regex version does ~123k ops/sec. **When automatically escaping the characters.**

You should review your view of "escaping is a performance hit".

If what you want is performance, then use the regex version.

PS: [Roel's version](http://jsperf.com/replaceall-regex-or-not/5) can be faster than regex.

Comment: Manual escape does not take time (I mean it takes YOUR time but not CPU time). But programmatic unescape is obviously takes some CPU time.

Comment: Here's the same test case **but including programmatic escaping** : http://jsperf.com/replaceall-regex-or-not/2

Comment: `while(replace)` is still 32% slower for me. I wonder if `indexOf()` is needed. Is there a way to know if `replace()` actually did something?

Comment: @dystroy included it in the answer.

Comment: @exebook no, no way to know that. `replace` returns the new string.

Comment: And unfortunately, javascript doesn't have multiple values returns.

Comment: Consider that indexOf and replace in the while loop both have to continuously look through the entire string over and over again every time a new match is found. For a long input string and many replacements I would expect that version to get slower and slower as the average string length grows. For realistic input I'd put my money on RegExp. Replacing "+" in the string "+ + +" seems a bit contrived. Is that really a good example of what your application is going to do?

Comment: What everybody should realize is that regular expressions **have been designed to be fast**. Nobody shoud try to avoid them "for performances" in simple cases !

Comment: @exebook when running with bigger strings (see the jsperf), the difference is much greater. ~8k vs ~123k.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, based on Florian Margaine's code and test case:

```
    window.replaceQuick = function(subject, search, replace) {
      var index = -1, offset = 0;
      var result = '';
      while ((index = subject.indexOf(search, offset)) !== -1) {
        result += subject.substring(offset, index) + replace;
        offset = index + search.length;
      }
      return result + search.substring(offset);
    }
```

Since I'm doing partial extractions it should get a better performance.

http://jsperf.com/replaceall-regex-or-not/3

Comment: Good point, yet still depends on use case and runtime. But generally regex is better. But as we mentioned earlier, premature optimization..

Comment: Plus one because yes... your implementation is faster in some cases (and as Florian pointed out, there was a bug in the perf test)

Comment: This proposed replaceQuick function is probably the best way to do it without RegExp so in that sense it answers the OP question best. But unless you *know* that you're running on a slow RegExp engine *and* that the performance impact actually matters, why bother? The RegExp will be probably be faster if you test across all browsers and use a variety of real input.